# Removing item from ListView.Builder always removes the last item in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, listitem, statefulwidget

When I tried to remove an item, every time the **last item** get removed. After searching for solutions, I found out it works this way with stateful widgets, and the solution is to add keys in the widgets.

So I added keys but the problem isn't gone. **The last item still gets removed**.
Bellow, I tried to show the situation as detailed as possible. At the very last, you will see, when I remove the item at index(0) it gets called but index(1) gets disposed from the UI. But in the list, the 1st item got removed properly.

> ***This is the ListView.builder***

```
                     ListView.builder(
                        primary: false,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: saleItems.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          print('Value key: ${ValueKey(index)}');
                          return ProductItemWidget(
                            key: ValueKey(index),
                            itemContext: context,
                            mainItems: batches,
                            onDelete: () {
                              setState(() {
                                saleItems.remove(saleItems[index]);
                                print(
                                    'deleted $index - value ${ValueKey(index)}');
                                print(saleItems);
                              });
                            },
                            onNewSaleItem: (newItem) {
                              setState(() {
                                saleItems[index] = newItem;
                              });
                              print(saleItems);
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

> ***Adding new items to the list***

```
SizedBox(
                        key: _addButtonKey,
                        child: KFilledButton(
                          text: 'New Sale Item',
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              saleItems.add(newSaleItemModal);
                            });
                            scrollToAddButton();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

> ***Instance of the item and the list***

```
  NewSaleItemModal newSaleItemModal = NewSaleItemModal();
  List<NewSaleItemModal> saleItems = [];
```

> > **ProductItemWidget() page**

> ***This is the Constructor***

```
class ProductItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  void Function() onDelete;
  List<dynamic>? mainItems;
  BuildContext? itemContext;
  Function(NewSaleItemModal newSaleItem) onNewSaleItem;
  ProductItemWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.onDelete,
    required this.onNewSaleItem,
    this.mainItems,
    this.itemContext,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProductItemWidget> createState() => _ProductItemWidgetState();
}
```

> ***These are the states***

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('Created with key: ${widget.key}');
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    types = profileRepository.getConfigEnums(type: EnumType.discountType);
    getAllProductNames();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    print('Disposed key: ${widget.key}');
    selectedProductName = null;
    selectedProduct = null;
    selectedType = null;
    _discountController.dispose();
    _rateController.dispose();
    _quantityController.dispose();
    _unitController.dispose();
    _amountController.dispose();
  }
```

> ***This is the where I added the key***

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext itemContext) {
    return Form(
      key: widget.key,
      child: ..........
      ),
     }
```

[image: After adding first item]

> > > ***After adding first item, in console...***

```
I/flutter (17380): Value key: [<0>]
I/flutter (17380): Created with key: [<0>]
I/flutter (17380): [NewSaleItemModal(productId: 23, batchId: 88, rate: 35567, quantity: 1, unitId: 1, discount: 0, discountType: null, amount: 35567)]
```

[image: After adding second item]

> > > ***After adding second item, in console...***

```
I/flutter (17380): Value key: [<1>]
I/flutter (17380): Created with key: [<1>]
I/flutter (17380): [NewSaleItemModal(productId: 23, batchId: 88, rate: 35567, quantity: 1, unitId: 1, discount: 0, discountType: null, amount: 35567), NewSaleItemModal(productId: 4, batchId: 69, rate: 1158, quantity: 1, unitId: 1, discount: 0, discountType: null, amount: 1158)]
```

[Here is the video deleting the first item](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jPKJM8I7HOoA27-XVsAHSvydeNlx5IE2/view?usp=sharing)

> > > ***When i delete the first item, in console...***

```
I/flutter (17380): deleted 0 - value [<0>]
I/flutter (17380): [NewSaleItemModal(productId: 4, batchId: 69, rate: 1158, quantity: 1, unitId: 1, discount: 0, discountType: null, amount: 1158)]

I/flutter (17380): Value key: [<0>]
I/flutter (17380): Disposed key: [<1>]
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm try using removeWhere to identify which item to be remove

```
saleItems.removeWhere((e)=> e.productId == saleItems[index].productId);
```

Comment: Thank you. But i think i can't use productId as a reference because productId will be null before selecting a product. Initially, the fields will be created but the value of the fields will be null.

Comment: have you tried only passing index only inside remove? like this? **saleItems.remove(index);**

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't remove anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UniqueKey()` instead of `ValueKey(index)`
It seems to have solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks!
It might solve the issue if I just passed the item's id in the ValueKey.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem in two my different projects, and sometimes even applied a "workaround" solution, like `Visibility(visible: !_isDeleted, child: MyListViewItem(...)` but I always ended up with the same approach:

**Use state management libraries**. E.g. ScopedModel, Redux or Bloc. This appeared to be the only correct way for me.

In a few words:

- Create a "model" that is always a "source of truth"
- All your listView items are just "lightweight" widgets that "reflect" the model (no matter stateful or stateless they are)
- Once you want to update => update only the model, and all listView items will draw whatever the model wants
- Want to delete? Just define and call `model.removeItemAt(i)`. All listView items will be rebuilt properly
- There will be some minor "issues" with updating widgets with user input, like text fields, numeric boxes, etc. This should not stop you. Define `TextEditingController`s for all text fields and update the model each time user changes the text

I hope it will help.